# Payable Function Solidity - What is the error: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm trying to make a simple transaction between two parts (Supplier and Producer).

First I made the contract deploy, then I defined the amount (that will be 1) and I made the transaction. Supplier defines the amount and consequently the price.

[image: amount transaction that works].

Before I execute the payable function and I change the Remix account (the producer will make this transaction), defining 1 ether in the value, that would be the purchase by the Producer.

[image: Inputs for the payble function]

When I execute the payable function, appears an error:
**The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.**

My code is below and I'm looking for an alternative to finalize the transaction between the two different accounts. **How I set the Producer in the right way?**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract supply {

address payable Supplier;
address payable Producer;
uint constant payment_unit = 1 ether;
uint public price_feature1_wei = 0;
string public features_product1;
bool public SellSuplier = true;
bool public contract_terminated = false;

constructor () public payable {
    Supplier = msg.sender;
    features_product1 = "product description...";

}

function PriceFeature1 (uint amount) public {
    require (SellSuplier == true);
    require (Supplier == msg.sender);
    price_feature1_wei = amount * payment_unit;
}

    function PurchaseFeature1() public payable {
    require (price_feature1_wei > 0);
    require (msg.value == price_feature1_wei);
    require (SellSuplier == true);
    require (Producer == msg.sender);
    require (Supplier.send(msg.value));
    SellSuplier = false;
}




}
```

Comment: Please do not use links or screenshots for error message, but edit the question and include any relevant information in the question itself.